# How to apply a macro to an array of names of targets in bazel?

Tags: build, bazel

I have a bazel package which has to generate a lot of executables (examples) using  the same macro that I wrote just for this case. Is it possible to apply it to an array of target names instead of listing them one by one like this?

```
simple_program(
    name = "example1",
)

simple_program(
    name = "example2",
)

simple_program(
    name = "example3",
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One advantage of just writing out all the rules you need is that your build file is much more declarative. The more logic there is in your build file (macros, etc), the harder it can become to figure out what's going on. With declarative build files, you can use tools like [Buildozer](https://github.com/bazelbuild/buildtools/tree/master/buildozer) to do large scale refactors.

That said, there are ways to do what you're asking. One is to use a list comprehension in your build file:

```
[simple_rule(name = n) for n in [
    "example1",
    "example2",
    "example3",
]]
```

Another is to use a macro, e.g.:

`defs.bzl`:

```
def generate_simple_rules(names):
  for name in names:
    simple_rule(name = name)
```

`BUILD`:

```
load("//:defs.bzl", "generate_simple_rules")
generate_simple_rules(["example1", "example2", "example3"])
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I didn't realize that all python syntax is allowed in build files.

Comment: Declarative build file is a good thing when there aren't too many repetitions of the same construct which makes it hard to do any modifications if necessary. Your last example to generate multiple rules is still declarative and doesn't repeat unnecessary code.

Comment: In addition to using macros and rules in build files, you can define variables and use list comprehensions, but that's about it. You can do much more in bzl files, but it's still a subset of python. See https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/language.html The macro example above is declarative, but Buildozer won't be able to modify the call to `simple_rule` in `generate_simple_rules`. Just something to keep in mind, because at scale, macros can be difficult for migrations/refactors.